# Is it possible to consume tick in a Forth definition?

Tags: forth

When reading about the tick (`'`) operator I wondered if it can be useful inside a word definition. I know that there is ['] to be used inside a definition, but I thought about using it to read the word name following invocation.

An example:

```
4 variable cnt

: cycle: ( arg fn -- )
  '
  4 cnt !
  begin
    cr
    dup execute
    -1 cnt +!
  cnt @ 0 = until
  drop
;
```

I can use `cycle:` to repeat some word invocation, as follows.

```
: hello ." hello" ;
cycle: hello
```

Which prints `hello` four times, as expected.

But the following code won't define a word that prints `hello` four times:

```
: 4hello cycle: hello ;
```

The tick operator still expects a word from the input stream following invocation of `4hello`.

Is it possible to inject it somehow when using `cycle:` in a word definition, so it won't "leak" outside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  You would have to make `cycle:` immediate.  And then also change it to postpone its actions, rather than perform them at runtime.

Postponing means to delay the actions of words.  Immediate words are compiled into the current definition, and normal words are arranged to be compiled when the current definition is executing.

In this case it might look something like this.

```
: (cycle)   4 0 do dup execute loop drop ;
: cycle:   ' postpone literal postpone (cycle) ; immediate
```

Note that this version no longer works outside definitions.

Comment: Thanks! That worked after one correction: `: (cycle)   >r 4 0 do j execute loop rdrop ;` (because loop counter is on return stack).

Comment: Right, sorry!  I'll rewrite to keep the xt on the data stack like your initial code.

Comment: That made my head spin! Perhaps throw in a couple of references (for further reading)?